# C# Abstract Class Operator Overload

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, Vector, which I would like to overload the operators +,-,*, etc.
I want any derived classes to be able to use these, and get an object back with the same type as the calling object.
I tried with generics, (as follows, in brief), but I couldn't find a legal way to do it:

```
public static T operator +<T>( T V1, T V2) where T : Vector
{
     //some calculation
     return new T(args);
}
```

I then tried to do it just using the base class:

```
    public static Vector operator+(Vector V1, Vector V2)
    {
        if (V1.Dimension != V2.Dimension)
            throw new VectorTypeException("Vector Dimensions Must Be Equal");
        double[] ArgList = new double[V1.Dimension];
        for (int i = 0; i < V1.Dimension; i++) { ArgList[i] = V1[i] + V2[i]; }

        return (Vector)Activator.CreateInstance(V1.GetType(), new object[] { ArgList});
    }
```

If this method is passed in two child objects, it should perform the operation on them, and return a new object of the same heritage.

The problem I ran into with this is that I cannot enforce that all such child classes must have a constructor with the appropriate signature, and I can't call the base constructor to make the object.

What are ways to either (a) Make either of these work, or (b) do this elegantly in another way?

Comment: How does your derived classes look like?

Comment: What would the result of `VectorA + VectorB` be, assuming both derive from `Vector`?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would need to subclass `Vector` (which appears to primarily be an array of `double`.) Could you explain a little more about your hierarchy?

Comment: Can you implement something like `protected abstract Vector Add(Vector otherVector)` methods?  This way your operators can call the virtual method on one and allow your child implementations to handle the work?

Comment: @dlev, yes it is primarily an array of double. However, there are several dimension specific properties that exist, such as being able to address members by .X & .Y for 2, .X, .Y & .Z for 3, and also the cross product for 3. I realize that for what I am using it for, detailing it for each case is trivial. But if I ever run across it again, I would like to have the best tools available.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, the result of a vector addition is the memberwise addition of each element, into a new vector of the same dimension.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905563/c-sharp-generic-operators) question.

Comment: @oleksii, I didn't find that one through my searching, thanks for ruling that out.
However, the second way I have chosen to do it works in all ways except knowing that the constructor exists for each possible subclass.

Comment: Side note: doing reflection in + operator will lead to very non-intuitive performance of code. Consider other approaches or very cleaver caching of reflection to avoid surprising performance hits.

Answer (score 13):

You could declare instance-level abstract methods which your subclass can override:

```
public abstract class Vector
{
    protected abstract Vector Add(Vector otherVector);

    public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2)
    {
        return v1.Add(v2);
    }
}

public class SubVector : Vector
{
    protected override Vector Add(Vector otherVector)
    {
        //do some SubVector addition
    }
}
```

Might run into some issues especially with multiple subclasses (Will `SubVector` have to know how to add with `SomeOtherSubVectorClass`?  What if you add `ThirdVectorType` class?) and perhaps handling null cases.  Also, making sure that `SubVector.Add` behaves the same as `SomeOtherSubVectorClass.Add` when it comes to commutative operations.

EDIT: based on your other comments, you could so something like:

```
public class Vector2D : Vector
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    protected override Vector Add(Vector otherVector)
    {
        Vector2D otherVector2D = otherVector as Vector2D;
        if (otherVector2D != null)
            return new Vector2D() { X = this.X + otherVector2D.X, Y = this.Y + otherVector2D.Y };

        Vector3D otherVector3D = otherVector as Vector3D;
        if (otherVector3D != null)
            return new Vector3D() { X = this.X + otherVector3D.X, Y = this.Y + otherVector3D.Y, Z = otherVector3D.Z };

        //handle other cases
    }
}


public class Vector3D : Vector
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    protected override Vector Add(Vector otherVector)
    {
        Vector2D otherVector2D = otherVector as Vector2D;
        if (otherVector2D != null)
            return new Vector3D() { X = this.X + otherVector2D.X, Y = this.Y + otherVector2D.Y, Z = this.Z };

        Vector3D otherVector3D = otherVector as Vector3D;
        if (otherVector3D != null)
            return new Vector3D() { X = this.X + otherVector3D.X, Y = this.Y + otherVector3D.Y, Z = this.Z + otherVector3D.Z };

        //handle other cases
    }
}
```

EDITx2:

Given your latest comment, perhaps your should just maintain an internal array/matrix and just do generic matrix math.  Your subclasses can expose X/Y/Z property wrappers against the array indicies:

```
public class Vector
{
    protected double[] Values;
    public int Length { get { return Values.Length; } }

    public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2)
    {
        if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
        {
            throw new VectorTypeException("Vector Dimensions Must Be Equal");
        }
        else
        {
            //perform generic matrix addition/operation
            double[] newValues = new double[v1.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
            {
                newValues[i] = v1.Values[i] + v2.Values[i];
            }

            //or use some factory/service to give you a Vector2D, Vector3D, or VectorND
            return new Vector() { Values = newValues };
        }
    }
}

public class Vector2D : Vector
{
    public double X
    {
        get { return Values[0]; }
        set { Values[0] = value; }
    }
    public double Y
    {
        get { return Values[1]; }
        set { Values[1] = value; }
    }
}


public class Vector3D : Vector
{
    public double X
    {
        get { return Values[0]; }
        set { Values[0] = value; }
    }
    public double Y
    {
        get { return Values[1]; }
        set { Values[1] = value; }
    }
    public double Z
    {
        get { return Values[2]; }
        set { Values[2] = value; }
    }
}
```

EDITx3: Based on your latest comment, I guess you could implement operator overloads on each subclass, do the shared logic in a static method (say in the base Vector class), and somewhere do a switch/case check to provide a specific subclass:

```
    private static Vector Add(Vector v1, Vector v2)
    {
        if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
        {
            throw new VectorTypeException("Vector Dimensions Must Be Equal");
        }
        else
        {
            //perform generic matrix addition/operation
            double[] newValues = new double[v1.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
            {
                newValues[i] = v1.Values[i] + v2.Values[i];
            }

            //or use some factory/service to give you a Vector2D, Vector3D, or VectorND
            switch (newValues.Length)
            {
                case 1 :
                    return new Vector1D() { Values = newValues };
                case 2 :
                    return new Vector2D() { Values = newValues };
                case 3 :
                    return new Vector3D() { Values = newValues };
                case 4 :
                    return new Vector4D() { Values = newValues };
                //... and so on
                default :
                    throw new DimensionOutOfRangeException("Do not support vectors greater than 10 dimensions");
                    //or you could just return the generic Vector which doesn't expose X,Y,Z values?
            }
        }
    }
```

Then your subclasses would have:

```
    public class Vector2D
    {
        public static Vector2D operator +(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2)
        {
            return (Vector2D)Add(v1, v2);
        }
    }

    public class Vector3D
    {
        public static Vector3D operator +(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2)
        {
            return (Vector3D)Add(v1, v2);
        }
    }
```

Some duplication, but I don't see a way around it off the top of my head to allow the compiler to do this:

```
    Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    var v3 = v1 + v2; //Vector3(3, 3, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(v3.X + ", " + v3.Y + ", " + v3.Z);
```

or for other dimensions:

```
    Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(2, 2);
    Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(1, 1);
    var v3 = v1 + v2; //Vector2(3, 3, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(v3.X + ", " + v3.Y); // no "Z" property to output!
```

Comment: In the case I am using, Vectors can only sum with each other if they are the same length. I am essentially trying for proper vector behaviour. But because all dimension vectors add in the same way, just with a different number of arguments, I want to only write it once.

Comment: Ahh, I edited after this comment.  Perhaps then you should treat your vectors with indexed arrays?  Do some length checks and perform the matrix math as needed in a generic way?

Comment: That is essentially what I have already, and posted. Where I am getting confused is the bit where the casting/new object creation occurs. If the return object is created as a child class, but passed out as a parent class, can it be returned to the child class?

Comment: See my last edit above.  Some code duplicationish, and an odd switch/case in the base class.  Could maybe move that switch/case to a dedicated factory.  Anyhow, not sure what else to do beyond that to maintain implicit typing to consumers of your vectors.

Answer (score 0):

What about having an abstract method called Add() that operator+ just acts as a wrapper for? ie, "return v1.Add(v2)". This would also enable you to define interfaces which non-Vector classes can constrain their code to, enabling to perform math-like operations (since generic code can't see/touch operators like +, -, etc for any type).

The only constructor you can code with in a generic method is the default (ie, parameter-less) constructor, which you have to specify in the generic constraints for the method/type.

Answer (score 0):

Five years later I had the exact same problem, only I was calling them Ntuples, not vectors. Here is what I did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

  public class Ntuple{
    /*parent class
    has an array of coordinates
    coordinate-wise addition method
    greater or less than in dictionary order
    */
    public List<double> Coords = new List<double>();
    public int Dimension;

    public Ntuple(List<double> Input){
      Coords=Input;
      Dimension=Input.Count;
    }//instance constructor

    public Ntuple(){
    }//empty constructor, because something with the + overload?


   public static Ntuple operator +(Ntuple t1, Ntuple t2)
   {
     //if dimensions don't match, throw error
     List<double> temp = new List<double>();
     for (int i=0; i<t1.Dimension; i++){
       temp.Add(t1.Coords[i]+t2.Coords[i]);
     }
     Ntuple sum = new Ntuple(temp);
     return sum;
   }//operator overload +

   public static bool operator >(Ntuple one, Ntuple other){
     //dictionary order
     for (int i=0; i<one.Dimension; i++){
       if (one.Coords[i]>other.Coords[i]) {return true;}
     }
     return false;
   }
   public static bool operator <(Ntuple one, Ntuple other){
     //dictionary order
     for (int i=0; i<one.Dimension; i++){
       if (one.Coords[i]<other.Coords[i]) {return true;}
     }
     return false;
   }

  }//ntuple parent class



  public class OrderedPair: Ntuple{
    /*
    has additional method PolarCoords, &c
    */
    public OrderedPair(List<double> Coords) : base(Coords){}
    //instance constructor
    public OrderedPair(Ntuple toCopy){
      this.Coords=toCopy.Coords;
      this.Dimension=toCopy.Dimension;
    }

  }//orderedpair

  public class TestProgram{
    public static void Main(){
      List<double> oneCoords=new List<double>(){1,2};
      List<double> otherCoords= new List<double>(){2,3};


      OrderedPair one = new OrderedPair(oneCoords);
      OrderedPair another = new OrderedPair(otherCoords);
      OrderedPair sum1 = new OrderedPair(one + another);


      Console.WriteLine(one.Coords[0].ToString()+one.Coords[1].ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(sum1.Coords[0].ToString()+sum1.Coords[1].ToString());

      bool test = one > another;
      Console.WriteLine(test);
      bool test2 = one < another;
      Console.WriteLine(test2);
    }
  }


}//namespace ntuples
```