# generic method where T implements operators

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)

I have the method

```
    public static T Add<T>(T x, T y) 
    {
        return x + y;
    }
```

and I obviosly get a compilation error because maybe the type T does not suppport the operator + . For example if I where to call the method as:

```
     Add<MyCar>(car1, car2);
```

It will not be possible to call that method because MyCar class does not have a definition for the `+` operator.

But it will make sence to call that method as:

```
    Add<Int32>(1,2);
```

So I remember I read long time ago that I had to place a where clause on the method in order to be able to compile it.  It was somethind like:

```
    public static T Add<T>(T x, T y) where T: "implements + operator"
    {
        return x + y;
    }
```

But I do not remember the syntax.

Comment: http://lmajsfy.com/?q=generic+type+math+operators

Comment: To my knowledge, C# generics do not allow for overloaded operators. This is discussed in more detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905563/c-sharp-generic-operators.

Comment: Your syntax `where T : constaint` is correct, however there is no constraint for operators. 

See [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for a list of available constraints.

Comment: You could convert the arguments to `dynamic`, if that is acceptable.