# Implicit Conversion to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, ienumerable, implicit-conversion

I have a class that is used to hold values loaded from a configuration file. To make this class easier to use, I have set up many implicit conversions to some basic types.

One of the types I would like to convert to is IEnumerable(T). For example, if the programmer has a value like this in the config file

```
a = "1,2,3,4"
```

In C# code, he can write

```
IEnumerable<int> a = Config.a;
```

Ideally what I would like to write is this

```
    public static implicit operator IEnumerable<T>(ConfigurationValue val)
    {
        string value = val;

        string[] parts = value.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        List<T> convertedTypes = new List<T>();

        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            T converted = Convert.ChangeType(part.Trim(), typeof(T));
            convertedTypes.Add(converted);
        }

        return convertedTypes;
    }
```

But this is giving me syntax errors that T is undefined. Is there no way to define such a conversion or is there a special syntax for it?

Also for the record I am using C# 4.0 in the .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate [C# Generic Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905563/c-sharp-generic-operators)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But this is giving me syntax errors that T is undefined. Is there no way to define such a conversion or is there a special syntax for it?

You're trying to declare a generic operator - and that's not supported in C#. (I don't know whether it's supported in IL.) The same is true for constructors, properties, events and finalizers.

Basically, only methods and types can be generic.

EDIT: As noted in comments, I'd write a generic method instead. User-defined conversions - particularly implicit ones - should be used *very* sparingly, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, would you recommend defining an implicit IEnumerable<int>, <string> , ... for each type I want to support or is there something cleaner you can recommend

Comment: @MaxEhrlich: I'd probably write a generic *method* instead of implicit conversions - I'm really not a fan of implicit conversions, especially ones which try to be "clever".

Comment: understood, I will experiment with both. I agree with you about implicit conversions and this is the only time I have ever used them. It is nice to think about these configuration values as having the proper type rather than something which needs to be converted.

Comment: +1 for recommendation to use user-defined conversion very sparingly

Answer (score 5):

Instead of generic operator (which is impossible as @Jon stated) you can create extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        yield break;

    var parts = value.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string part in parts)
        yield return Convert.ChangeType(part.Trim(), typeof(T));
}
```

And use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> a = Config.a.AsEnumerable<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet mentioned generic operators aren't supported, but you could make it a generic extension method instead.

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(this ConfigurationValue val)
    {
        string value = val.Value;

        string[] parts = value.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        List<T> convertedTypes = new List<T>();

        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            T converted = (T)Convert.ChangeType(part.Trim(), typeof(T));
            convertedTypes.Add(converted);
        }

        return convertedTypes;
    }
}
```