# Binary operator for a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

Is there a way to make this code compile?

```
class Foo<T>
{
    ...
}

...

var a = new Foo<int>();
var b = new Foo<string>();
var c = a + b;
```

It seems that C# allows to specify neither `operator+(Foo<int> a, Foo<string> b)`, nor `operator+<U>(Foo<T> a, Foo<U> b)`. Given that I can easily create `operator +(Foo a, Bar b)` for non-generic `Foo` and `Bar`, this restriction, if it exists, seems to be somewhat weird.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/756995/961113

Comment: I don't think that question has a lot to do with mine. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This one should be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905563/c-sharp-generic-operators

Comment: These questions are vaguely related to mine, if at all. Perhaps I should make the question more clear.

Comment: And what type of the result will be?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, Marc Gravell's generic operators [solution](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) should fit the bill, and that was linked in the accepted answer for one of the questions already brought up as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There are no generic operators supportion in C#. Moreover you can't declare generic type restrictions which means that *"this generic type has some operators"*. There are to ways to solve this.

First is to use **Expressions**. You can read about it in Marc Gravells [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html).

Second is to use **dynamic**. For example, generic **Add()** method may looks like this without exceptions:

```
public static T Add<T>(T arg1, T arg2)
{
    dynamic a1 = arg1;
    dynamic a2 = arg2;
    return a1 + a2;
}
```

In both cases you may have some unpleasant surprises during the runtime.

But as I understand you want to add two objects of different types. **Foo< int>** is not the same as **Foo< string>** and I think this even has no sense. What the result of this adding will be? Anyway you may declare your method like this:

```
public static T1 Add<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
    dynamic a1 = arg1;
    dynamic a2 = arg2;
    return a1 + a2;
}
```

This method can succesfully add **int** to **string**(but not vice versa):

```
Console.WriteLine(Add("hello", 1));
```

You may try to add anything to anything but you must have appropriate version of operator overloading to have no exceptions. Another example:

```
class MyClass<T>
{

    public static MyClass<T> operator +(MyClass<T> c1, MyClass<int> c2)
    {
        return new MyClass<T>();
    }

}

//...

// Add MyClass<string> to MyClass<int>. 
// As you can see we have appropriate version of operator overloading for doing this without exceptions.
var c1 = new MyClass<string>();
var c2 = new MyClass<int>();
var res = Add(c1, c2);
```

Comment: Perhaps it should have been clarified in the question text: I don't intend to do any actual addition on generic values inside the plus operator, so the first part of the answer is not relevant. What I want to do is to implicitly build a tree corresponding to some arithmetic expression involving members of my custom type. Overloading with just one argument type fully specified seems to do the trick, thanks.